# undefined method `strftime' for nil:NilClass - shows sometimes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building a simple app for displaying movies using [themoviedb](https://github.com/ahmetabdi/themoviedb) gem. However, when I try to do a search query, it displays the error I mentioned. Now, that doesn't happen *every time* - only in certain cases (e.g. Matrix works fine, but Fight Club shows the error)

Here's my code:

```
<% @movie.each do |movie| %>
<%= link_to movie_path(movie.id) do %>
<%= image_tag("#{@configuration.base_url}w154#{movie.poster_path}") if movie.poster_path %>
<% end %>
<div class="moviesindex">
<%= link_to movie.title, movie_path(movie.id) %>
(<%= movie.release_date.to_date.strftime("%Y") %>) <br />
</div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: after the call to strftime add "rescue movie.inspect" to see what the movie object looks like, my hunch is the release_date is invalid or empty.

Comment: the only reason is if release_date is nil means not saved in databse,then u will get this type error...u can check in your rails console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be forgiving for `realease_date` if `movie.release_date` can be nil at times using `try`:

```
<%= movie.release_date.try(:year) %>
```

This will give you release year if release_date is valid and gives you nil if release_date is nil.

Since `release_date`, I assume is already either a `Date` or `DateTime` or `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`, the `to_date` is not necessary.  Also I think `date.year` is more cleaner than `date.strftime("%Y")`.

Comment: I used *to_date* before *try*, otherwise it just returned empty parentheses.